# How to import sql file into a bash script

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, bash, debian

On Debian, I want to import a huge sql file with a command in a bash script. Currently, I use this command:

```
mysql -u root -p myDatabase < my_backup.sql
```

But that's not fine in a bash script because it asks for the root password ! I tried to provide it in the command with the -p argument, but it doesn't seems to work... Do someone have a solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no space between the "-p" and your password.

Per mysql documentation:

These work:

```
-uuser_name -ppassword 
-u user_name -ppassword
```

This does not:

```
-u user_name -p password
```

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,229253

Comment: I tried mysql -u root -p="mypassword" myDatabase < my_backup.sql, but it denies the access... :(

Comment: You need to drop the equals sign and double-quotes.